# Excel IF function returning 0 instead of intended text, even when "formula result" shows text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns.

```
     A                B
| French Word  | New Translation |
| --------     | --------        |
| Inconnu      |                 |
| Mise a jour  | Mis à jour      |
```

If the "New Translation" cell is blank, I would like it to be populated using the "French Word" found in the same row. Using the formula "IF(TRIM(B2)="",A2,B2)" returns 0. When I try to build it out using the function builder it says the formula result will be the correct, then executing the function results in "0" again. [Formula Builder view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4ry8.jpg) (<- this one has D2="0" since it was the value at the time- I was just trying to get it to evaluate to True) [Actual Rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXVTv.jpg)

I have the most recent version of Excel. I assume this is a circular reference problem but I am a noob at excel and don't know what other way to fix it. Thanks for reading!

I have set both column formats to "Text" and neither columns are vlookup based.

```
=IF(TRIM(B2)="",A2,B2)

=IF(B2="",A2,B2)

=IF(ISBLANK(B2),A2,B2)
```

Comment: If cell B2 is empty then 0 is correct.

Comment: `I assume this is a circular reference problem` - yes, it is. How do you imagine a cell containing both a formula and a user-provided value? `what other way to fix it` - create a third column and put that formula there.

Comment: If the formula results in False, the intended result is that the cell in column B remains the same. Is there a way to reference that without circular reference? @GSerg

Comment: How would the cell in column B contain the intended result in the first place, if it already contains the formula?

Comment: If you are able to add a third column you could just do the calculation there.  i.e. in C2 just put =IF(TRIM(B2)="",A2,B2).

Comment: " the intended result is that the cell in column B remains the same" d u mean the input cell for the formula is the same as the formula cell (output)?